# 2005 Chevy avalanche 1500 died while driving and won’t start now

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, power-loss, avalanche

I was driving down the road and all of a sudden my truck just died when I tried restarting it it wouldn’t even crank over  remind you the battery is new  so I know it’s not thAt  all lights are still bright so got it towed home and when I took the key out the dash lights would not go off  we had to disconnect the battery the next morning we connected the battery it started right up ran then shut off    Then it starts and then dies  we tried switching all the relays starter is good alternator battery is good nobody knows what’s wrong they belive it could be the ignition failing to communicate with the cluster  so it shuts the trucks off any ideas

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you tried the key when it wouldn't start, you got nothing out of it? No noises as you turned the key (other than the key itself)?

Comment: A little clicking noise sounded like it was comming from under the dash it starts and runs for about a hour then shuts off now and then won’t crank over then it will then it won’t and the dash lights are staying on after I shut the truck off the garage is clue less they don’t know what’s goin on

Comment: And there is only 1 code on it that’s a code saying the ignition is failing to communicate with the dashboard cluster